# How to code not continuous numeric value

Tags: svm, libsvm

I'm preparing data for SVM. One row contains kind of category values

```
80, 160, 320, etc. (5*2^n)
```

Practical value-range is [80:10240]

I wonder if I should scale the range [80:10240] to -1:1 and use as simple feature.

Another possibility would be to split the range to 8 flag-features all having values -1 or 1 (like it is suggested for attribute features in libsvm guide)

I'm using libsvm implementation of SVM. Could you give me an advice, which method would give more accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to say without doing some experimentation but [80:10240] sounds like a big range to squeeze it on -1:1 but still might work. I think that another option would be to take just the n value (i.e log(x/5)) so your range would be [4:11] which sounds more manageable.

Comment: I believe the scaled range is not an issue, since the values are doubles in LibSVM. -1:1 is the default range in scale-tool, so i think this scale is reasonable. I meant rather, since I could code the values as attributes, if I should do so. Maybe attribute-features could provide more accuracy over a simple value.

Comment: Oh I believe I didn't explain myself properly. The problem is not the range -1:1, that's a very good scale for SVM. The problem is the original range [80:10240] that would create very small values when they are traslated to the range [-1:1], and very small values can result in numeral problem to the optimization problem. That said, it is a matter of testing anyway.

Comment: Ok, I think, I understand now! You mean making the value range more linear before scaling it? That's a good approach I haven't considered so far (I'm very new to SVM and don't know all the "tricks"). Indeed I would prefer coding this as one feature instead of splitting it to attributes. The reason is, sometimes the values (actually  sample titrations) don't follow the rule 5*2^n but are 100, 200, etc. Using single feature wouldn't require mapping of such non-standard values to attributes.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz Now that you said it is for sample titrations I am very curious about what is your goal with this. Are you solving a classification or a regression problem?

Comment: I believe it is a classification problem. I'm trying to estimate the end point titer having the beginning titration, microscope image and some lightning factors as parameters. End point titer is the titration, when the sample looks like negative. There is pixel intensity as well as basic patter analysis involved.